# Slow SQL Server performance with multiple PreparedStatement loop

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have a need to update thousands of database records at a time. I am using a loop to generate the necessary `PreparedStatement` updates, but am hoping for a more efficient method.

Normally, I would try to use a batch operation, but since the number of fields I need to update for each record differs, I need a new `PreparedStatement` for each update.

As it is, updates around 2,000 records takes 3-4 minutes.

```
            for (AgentUpdate update : updateList) {

                Agent thisAgent = update.getAgent();

                // Prefix for updating each agent
                StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(
                        "UPDATE REP_ASSIST.AGENTS SET\n"
                );

                // Create a map of all changes
                Map<String, String> updateMap = new HashMap<>();
                for (AgentDiffs diff : update.getChanges()) {
                    updateMap.put(diff.getAgentField().toString(), diff.getNewValue());
                }

                // Iterate through the map and build the SQL statement,
                // including all fields to be updated
                Iterator iterator = updateMap.entrySet().iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
                    sql.append(pair.getKey()).append("=?");

                    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        sql.append(",\n");
                    }
                }
                sql.append("\nWHERE AGENT_CODE=? AND UPN=?;");
                Utility.printTempMsg(sql.toString());

                // Create the PreparedStatement and fill each ? with the
                // appropriate new value.
                ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
                int paramNum = 1;
                for (String fieldName : updateMap.keySet()) {
                    String newValue = updateMap.get(fieldName);
                    ps.setString(paramNum, newValue);

                    // Increase the parameter count
                    paramNum++;
                }

                // We are now to our last two parameters, fill them
                ps.setString(paramNum++, thisAgent.getAgentCode());
                ps.setInt(paramNum, thisAgent.getAgentUpn());

                ps.executeUpdate();
                count++;

                Utility.printTempMsg(sql.toString());

                // Update the progress based on total count so far
                updateProgress(count, totalOperations);


            }
```

So how does one handle large dynamic updates of this sort?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some ideas to try:

1. You are not closing your `PreparedStatement`s.  There might possibly be some slow down due to resource consumption or deadlock.  Use the try-with-resources feature so it will automatically close.

   ```
   for (AgentUpdate update : updateList) {
       try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql.toString())
       {
           // set parameters
           ps.executeUpdate();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Alternatively, you are creating a custom query and creating a new `PreparedStatement` for each record.  Although you are optimizing individual queries by minimizing the number of fields you are updating, you are creating additional overhead by preparing a new statements for each record.  If you update every field for every row, you could re-use the same `PreparedStatement`, which may end up being more efficient (depending on the number of fields and length of data you are actually updating).  Just overwrite the values in the prepared statement and redo the `executeUpdate()` on it.

   ```
   try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql.toString())) {
       for (AgentUpdate update : updateList) {
           // set parameters
           ps.executeUpdate();
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need to create a `HashMap` because you already have an object `AgentDiffs` to hold the values for you. Creating a `HashMap` is just an unnecessary step here.

To create the `UPDATE` statement, you may directly use `Stream` instead of iterating over a `HashMap`

```
String fields = update.getChanges().stream()
                .map(diff -> diff.getAgentField().toString() + "=?")
                .collect(Collectors.joining(",\n"));
```

And after that, you may iterate the `AgentDiffs` again to fill the values of the parameters in `PreparedStatement`.

Try to break down your block of code into separate functions.

I hope someone provides a better way to improve the SQL performance you are looking for.

Comment: Does using the `stream` ensure the values fields are added in list order? If not, I have no way of knowing which parameter would need to hold each value...

Comment: It will be sequential maintaining the original order unless you use `parallel()` or `parallelStream()`.